# What's the similar word for Answer Sheet?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

There is a quiz section on my blog, and a list of quiz result. I need a title for the list of quiz results. I prefer not to use "Replies" because I've already used it up in forum discussions. "Submission" sounds not good enough because it feels like "surrender".  "Answer" is close but it's been used up in other part of the blog, too. Is there a single word for this?

Comment: So, by *results*, you mean "answers to the quiz given by respondants, that may or may not be correct"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I need a title for the list of quiz results."

Can you just use this?

> Quiz Results

Seems to be the most straightforward, and have the clearest meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Why not "[Solutions"](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/solutions)? (definition number 5)

**UPDATE**

I think I'm not getting the meaning you are looking for. If you have a blog and you just want to show answers to a quiz "Solutions" seems to be [valid](http://www.examswithsolutions.com/Subjects/physics_exams.html). If you want to apply corrections to the answers submitted by users "Test Results" or "Results" seems to be more accurate.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I feel solution should be an answer provided by a person who is more knowledgeable. Is it normal if I use it on student's answer?

Comment: Most of the results need to apply corrections, but some is just for fun. I also think Result is more accurate. But I prefer not to make visitors to think twice--"what kind of result?"

Answer (score 1):

**Responses** or **User Responses**:

I have to do a fair number of online continuing education credits, and these invariably have a competency test at the end. Most of them use the format of **Your Response** or **Your Answer** in this regard.

The scoring page is usually labelled **Results** with each entry in the form of:

> Question: Who's buried in Grant's Tomb?
>   Your Response: B. Ulysses S. Grant
>   Correct Response:  C. No one, it's a mausoleum.

If you wish to convey the results *overall* of everyone taking the quiz. Individual scores in a list, average score, etc.  This would be headed by a column that says **Results**, **Top Answerers**, etc. depending upon context.

Answer (score 0):

Responses. [insert explanation of this answer here]

Comment: Rather than adding filler, you should provide a more substantial answer, such as by explaining why your choice would fit the context.

Comment: I can't quite flag this as low-quality because it is an answer.  But, it's darned close!

Answer (score 0):

How about

> Answer Keys
>   or just
>   Keys

Comment: That is the list of correct answers by which you judge the submitted answers.

Answer (score 0):

Either results or responses.

Results is more objective, responses more subjective.

Are these quizzes designed to test visitors knowledge OR polling to collect visitors views, even allow composed responses? Your use of quiz & answer sheet makes it sound like the former but blogs tend more toward the latter.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a competition, "entries" might be the best choice.